# Use output of procedure in a new procedure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that returns an output, ID. Say it works like tihs:

```
PROCEDURE IssuerID
   @ID INT OUTPUT

BEGIN

-- assigns a value to ID somehow

END
```

And now I am working with another stored procedure. In this procedure, I execute the stored procedure IssuerID, and I would like to use the output of IssuerID for something. I tried to do it like this:

```
PROCEDURE IssuerID2

BEGIN
   EXEC IssuerID

select top 1 ID from RandomTable where ID = (Output of EXEC IssuerID)
END
```

However, it did not work out. Any ideas?

Comment: You aren't consuming the `OUTPUT` parameter in your `EXEC` statement. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver16#return-data-using-an-output-parameter) demonstrates how to pass and consume (output) parameters.

Comment: As a separate note, using `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` is a sure sign of a flaw. This means that the data engine is free to return what ever arbitrary row(s) it wants, and the row(s) could be different every time you run said query. If you are using `TOP` you need to ensure the query has an `ORDER BY` so that you get consistent and reliable results.

Comment: Sadly Full Stack yes it did. Thank you!

Comment: Larnu thank you I am aware of this, was just a very very quick example :D

Comment: I don't see how the accepted dupe is correct. The duplicate is about consuming the returned **result set(s)** from a procedure, *not* an `OUTPUT` parameter.